# Windows 10 - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, iis, windows-10

[image]

Greetings guys,

I experience this issue after I upgrade my pc to windows 10 from windows 7.
Previously when I was using windows 7, I did not face this type of issue even once.

I've seen multiple questions regarding this issue, but none explained related to my question, or I have overlooked.

Therefore, I suspect this is caused because of the windows upgrade.
Please correct me if I am wrong, what's the solution for this issue?

Adding on information, when I try to search for the displayed config file path:

```
\\?\C:\Users\Developer\Documents\My Web Sites\Webapp-Site31\web.config
```

I found that it is not the correct path. And the "Webapp-Site31" is not in the folder as well.

[image]

Comment: An upgrade can easily lead to missing OOB components, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution,

Whenever you face this issue, You will have to delete a hidden folder ".vs" at your solution's root folder and close and reopen your solution and run. Then the issue would be solved.[image]

How to see hidden folder?

[image]

Control Panel > File Explorer Options > click View Tab > Select Show hidden files, and drives > Apply > OK